# How division rotates complex number in direction opposite to multiplication?

Tags: complex-numbers

At [1:06](https://www.youtube.com/live/5PcpBw5Hbwo?si=UkloItEyFF4TlbCG&t=3987) timestamp of 3b1b Complex numbers fundamental video, Grant says $$\text{cis}(\alpha)=\frac{1}{\text{cis}(-\alpha)}$$ where $$\text{cis}(\alpha)=\cos(\alpha)+i\sin(\alpha)$$

He seem to give the fact that multiplying vector by constant $>1$ is equivalent to stretching the vector while by constant $<1$ is equivalent to squishing the vector

However, I dont get how vectors gets flipped vertically when taken inverse, that is I dont get how $\text{cis}(\alpha)=\frac{1}{\text{cis}(-\alpha)}$

I tried to visualize it:

[image]

I confirmed this fact by quickly writing a python code. Also tried to prove this by pen pensil for $\alpha=45^o$ and then algebraically proving $\text{cis}(\alpha)=\frac{1}{\text{cis}(-\alpha)}$. But I am not able to reason out same geometrically / visually. What I am missing here?

Comment: $$\frac{1}{\cos x + i \sin x} = \frac{\cos x - i \sin x}{(\cos x + i \sin )(\cos x - i \sin x)}  $$ and $\cos^2 + \sin^2 =1$

Comment: $\text{cis}(\alpha)$ is litteraly $e^{i\alpha}$, so if $\text{cis}(\alpha)=e^{i\alpha}$ you have $\text{cis}(-\alpha)=e^{-i\alpha}=\frac{1}{\text{cis}(\alpha)}$

Comment: Thanks @RolandF and MathAttack, for giving me yet two new ways to prove this algebraically. But I was looking for **visual / geometrical intuition** of "why inversing $cis(-\alpha)$ **vertically flips** the vector to give $cis(\alpha)$".

Comment: What is your visual intuition about the meaning of "dividing by a vector"? I know what it means for a scalar.

Comment: As Grant stated in the video, multiplication corresponds to rotation. Division should mean same.

Answer (score 1):

When you multiply $z$ by $1/z$, you get $1$. Therefore, the angles for $z$ and $1/z$ sum to $0$ and their magnitudes are multiplicative inverses. Thus, if $z=r\,\text{cis}(\alpha)$, we will have $1/z=(1/r)\text{cis}(-\alpha)$.

Comment: So it is kind of part of the definition of this coordinate system (imaginary part on $y$ axis and real part on $x$ axis)? That is "by definition" multiplying by $z$ means rotating couter clockwise and dividing by $z$ means rotating clockwise? And nothing more involved happening here?

Comment: I suppose you can say that, but if $z$ has negative imaginary part, I think of multiplication by $z$ as rotating clockwise.

Answer (score 0):

Division in the Argand plane also means rotation, like multiplication, but in the opposite direction.

If you multiply a number by $\operatorname{cis}(\alpha)$ it rotates the point (or "vector" as you put it) that represents the number by an angle $\alpha$ counterclockwise.
Dividing by $\operatorname{cis}(\alpha)$ reverses the multiplication by
$\operatorname{cis}(\alpha)$, that is, it rotates the point by an angle $\alpha$ clockwise.

So if you multiply or divide the number $1$ by $\operatorname{cis}(\alpha)$,
obtaining $\operatorname{cis}(\alpha)$ itself (in the case of multiplication)
or $1/\operatorname{cis}(\alpha)$ (in the case of division),
you get points that are rotated from the point $1 + i0$ through an angle
$\alpha$ counterclockwise or an angle $\alpha$ clockwise, respectively.

The two rotations are mirror images of each other and produce mirror-imaged points.

The fact that this looks like a reflection across the $x$ axis is just a consequence of the symmetry of the rotations.
The underlying reasons for this result are really about rotations, not reflection.